# 802.11n CSI tool

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, 802.11n

I am trying to run a [CSI tool](http://dhalperi.github.io/linux-80211n-csitool/)

Installation went OK. I can connect to an 802.11n no security AP (ZTE ZXHN H168N V3.1), HT rate, 40 MHz BW; I can ping the AP, but no messages are displayed in the CSI terminal, and the CSI log file remains empty. Can anyone please help?

Comment: You have an Intel Wi-Fi Wireless Link 5300 WLAN card, and you've installed the modified firmware? Otherwise it won't work ...

Comment: Correct. Intel WiFi Link 5300 + modified firmware. Followed the instructions. No results displayed/logged.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turned out that I had not installed the tool properly. You have to check that each step of the installation instructions is successfully executed. In my case my Ubuntu kernel version wasn't allowing the following command to work (on step 2):

```
git pull --no-edit ubuntu ${UBUNTU_KERNEL_TAG}
```

I would suggest using a 3.13.0 Ubuntu kernel version, as 4.2 and 4.4 do not seem to work in most cases.

Comment: I reverted to Ubuntu 12.04 and everything works fine. I'm not 100% sure, but in step 2 I might have typed `git pull ubuntu ${UBUNTU_KERNEL_TAG}`.